# Reading shapefiles inside nested zip archives

Tags: python, zip, geopandas, shapefile

I have a big zip archive "Polska_SHP.zip" that contains another zip archives (named "02_SHP.zip", "04_SHP.zip" etc.). Each of these archives contains another zip archives (for example archive "02_SHP.zip" has "0201_SHP.zip", "0202_SHP.zip inside and so on). Finally, these archives contain many shapefiles, and I need to read all shapefiles with "SWRS" in the name into one geopandas dataframe. So far I've been able to search for the names of these shapefiles and I've tried to read them:

```
import zipfile
from io import BytesIO
import geopandas as gpd

with zipfile.ZipFile("Polska_SHP.zip", "r") as main_zfile:
    for name in main_zfile.namelist(): # lista archiwów w głównym folderze
        print("name: ", name)
        if ".zip" in name:
            zfiledata = BytesIO(main_zfile.read(name))
            with zipfile.ZipFile(zfiledata) as zfile2:
                for name2 in zfile2.namelist():
                    print("name2: ", name2)
                    if ".zip" in name2:
                        zfiledata2 = BytesIO(zfile2.read(name2))
                        with zipfile.ZipFile(zfiledata2) as zfile3:
                            for name3 in zfile3.namelist():
                                if "SWRS" in name3 and ".shp" in name3:
                                    print("name3: ", name3)
                                    gdf = gpd.read_file(name3)
                                    gdf.head()
```

and it prints the name I need:

```
name:  32_SHP.zip
name2:  32/3209_SHP.zip
name3:  PL.PZGiK.339.3209__OT_SWRS_L.shp
```

but it fails when it comes to reading shapefile:

> CPLE_OpenFailedError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
> fiona/_shim.pyx in fiona._shim.gdal_open_vector()
> fiona/_err.pyx in fiona._err.exc_wrap_pointer()
> CPLE_OpenFailedError: PL.PZGiK.339.3209__OT_SWRS_L.shp: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

The `name3` variable you are passing to `gpd.read_file()` is just the name of the file in ZIP, for this to work you would first have to extract the ZIP.

Another option would be passing the file-like object of the archive, though this assumes there's only one dataset included in the zip and shp-file with all its friends are in top level directory. Please note that my sample had just **2** levels of nested archives. And shapefiles had different attributes, thus a list of geodataframes - `gdfs` -  is used to collect all the data. In your case you probably want to use [`pandas.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat).
(BTW, your current loop attempts to overwrite `gdf` each time)

```py
# python     : 3.8.13
# geopandas  : 0.10.2
# fiona      : 1.8.18

import geopandas as gpd
import zipfile
import re

# shp_regex = "SWRS.*\.shp$"
shp_regex = "^ne_.*\.shp$"

# list of geodataframes
gdfs = []
with zipfile.ZipFile("nat_earth.zip", "r") as main_zfile:
    main_zfile.printdir()
    print("- " * 40)
    # only cycle through *.zip files
    for name in [fname for fname in main_zfile.namelist() if fname.endswith(".zip")]:
        print(f'>> {name}:')
        with main_zfile.open(name, "r") as zipped_shp:
            zipped_shp_namelist = zipfile.ZipFile(zipped_shp).namelist()
            print(", ".join(zipped_shp_namelist))
            # check if any of the files actually matches the pattern
            if any(re.search(shp_regex, level2_fname) for level2_fname in zipped_shp_namelist):
                # for gpd.read_file() file position must be changed back to 0
                zipped_shp.seek(0)
                gdfs.append(gpd.read_file(zipped_shp))
                rows, cols = gdfs[-1].shape
                print(f'GeoDataFrame: {rows} rows, {cols} columns\n')

# head of first gdf
print(gdfs[0].head())
```

Output:

```bash
File Name                                             Modified             Size
ne_50m_admin_0_countries.zip                   2021-12-08 03:47:44       792663
ne_50m_lakes.zip                               2021-12-08 03:49:54       252615
ne_50m_ocean.zip                               2021-09-04 08:56:52       461745
ne_50m_rivers_lake_centerlines.zip             2021-12-08 03:49:54       504454
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
>> ne_50m_admin_0_countries.zip:
ne_50m_admin_0_countries.README.html, ne_50m_admin_0_countries.VERSION.txt, 
ne_50m_admin_0_countries.cpg, ne_50m_admin_0_countries.dbf, 
ne_50m_admin_0_countries.prj, ne_50m_admin_0_countries.shp, 
ne_50m_admin_0_countries.shx
GeoDataFrame: 242 rows, 162 columns

>> ne_50m_lakes.zip:
ne_50m_lakes.README.html, ne_50m_lakes.VERSION.txt, ne_50m_lakes.cpg, 
ne_50m_lakes.dbf, ne_50m_lakes.prj, ne_50m_lakes.shp, ne_50m_lakes.shx
GeoDataFrame: 412 rows, 40 columns

>> ne_50m_ocean.zip:
ne_50m_ocean.README.html, ne_50m_ocean.VERSION.txt, ne_50m_ocean.cpg, 
ne_50m_ocean.dbf, ne_50m_ocean.prj, ne_50m_ocean.shp, ne_50m_ocean.shx
GeoDataFrame: 1 rows, 4 columns

>> ne_50m_rivers_lake_centerlines.zip:
ne_50m_rivers_lake_centerlines.README.html, 
ne_50m_rivers_lake_centerlines.VERSION.txt, 
ne_50m_rivers_lake_centerlines.cpg,  
ne_50m_rivers_lake_centerlines.dbf, ne_50m_rivers_lake_centerlines.prj, 
ne_50m_rivers_lake_centerlines.shp, ne_50m_rivers_lake_centerlines.shx
GeoDataFrame: 478 rows, 37 columns

        featurecla  scalerank  LABELRANK SOVEREIGNT SOV_A3  ADM0_DIF  LEVEL  \
0  Admin-0 country          1          3   Zimbabwe    ZWE         0      2   
1  Admin-0 country          1          3     Zambia    ZMB         0      2   
2  Admin-0 country          1          3      Yemen    YEM         0      2   
3  Admin-0 country          3          2    Vietnam    VNM         0      2   
4  Admin-0 country          5          3  Venezuela    VEN         0      2   
... 
                                            geometry  
0  POLYGON ((31.28789 -22.40205, 31.19727 -22.344...  
1  POLYGON ((30.39609 -15.64307, 30.25068 -15.643...  
2  MULTIPOLYGON (((53.08564 16.64839, 52.58145 16...  
3  MULTIPOLYGON (((104.06396 10.39082, 104.08301 ...  
4  MULTIPOLYGON (((-60.82119 9.13838, -60.94141 9...  

[5 rows x 162 columns]
```